# Second-derivative finite-difference approximation: What is the correct order?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

The "standard" second-derivative centered finite-difference approximation is given by [LeVeque](http://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/fdmbook/) as
\begin{equation}
u''(x)\approx\frac{u(x+h)+u(x-h)-2u(x)}{h^2}\,.
\end{equation}
So if I insert
\begin{equation}
u(x+h)=u(x)+h u'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 u''(x)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 u^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{24} h^4 u^{(4)}(x)+\mathcal{O}\left(h^5\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
u(x-h)=u(x)-h u'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 u''(x)-\frac{1}{6} h^3 u^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{24} h^4 u^{(4)}(x)+\mathcal{O}\left(h^5\right)
\end{equation}
into the first equation, the $u(x)$, $u'(x)$, and $u'''(x)$ terms cancel, and the rest are divided by $h^2$ to give
\begin{equation}
u''(x)+\frac{1}{12} h^2 u^{(4)}(x)+\mathcal{O}\left(h^3\right)\,.
\end{equation}
Here I am assuming that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathcal{O}(h^5)}{h^2}=\mathcal{O}(h^3)\,.
\end{equation}
But LeVeque says the result should be
\begin{equation}
u''(x)+\frac{1}{12} h^2 u^{(4)}(x)+\mathcal{O}\left(h^4\right)\,.
\end{equation}
Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: *All* of the odd degree terms cancel, provided enough regularity for them to even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get the answer from the comment, write one more term.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u(x+h)&=u(x)+hu'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 u''(x)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 u^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{24} h^4 u^{(4)}(x)+\frac{1}{120} h^5 u^{(5)}(x)+\operatorname{O}\left(h^6\right) \\
u(x-h)&=u(x)-hu'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 u''(x)-\frac{1}{6} h^3 u^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{24} h^4 u^{(4)}(x)-\frac{1}{120} h^5 u^{(5)}(x)+\operatorname{O}\left(h^6\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Add these two equations and observe that the odd degree terms cancel out.
\begin{equation}
u(x+h)+u(x-h)=2u(x)+h^2\left(u''(x)+\frac{1}{12} h^2 u^{(4)}(x)+\operatorname{O}\left(h^4\right)\right)
\end{equation}
This shows the desired error of the centered finite-difference approximation of the second derivative.
$$\frac{u(x+h)+u(x-h)-2u(x)}{h^2}=u''(x)+\frac{1}{12} h^2 u^{(4)}(x)+\operatorname{O}\left(h^4\right)$$

Comment: Note that this almost entirely follows by symmetry considerations: $\frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2}$ is invariant under $h \mapsto -h$.